# Compute $\int \int_{S} (y^2 +2 y z)dS$ over the plane $2x + y+ 2z=6 $

Tags: integration

I have to calculate this integral

$$\iint_{S} (y^2 +2 y z)dS$$

over the plane $2x + y+ 2z=6$ in the first octant

I used the explicit representation $x=\frac{6-y-2z}{2}$ and have the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{6-y}\left(y^2 + 2 y z \space\right)\sqrt{1+1+ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\space \space dz dy =\frac{243}{4}$$

I used mathematics to calculate it, therefore there are no calculation errors. However I have the solution and I know that the result is $\frac{243}{2}$. Have I proposed the integral well? Where is the error?

Thanks

Comment: Your plane intersects the $yz$-plane in the line $y+2z=6$. This line has $y$-intercept at $(0,6,0)$. Why does your $dy$ integral only run from $0$ to $3$?

Comment: Also, the integral over ${\rm d}z$ should be from $0$ to $3-\frac{y}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a mistake in the boundary of your limits. You have that $0 \le z \le \frac{6-y}{2}$ and $0 \le y \le 6$. Try evaluating the integral with this boundaries. To get a better understanding I would recommend sketching the projection on the $yz$-plane.